# Why does the new Google Analytics snippet use bracket notation?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

The new Google Analytics snippet uses the following code:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Which triggers two errors and a warning in JSHint:

```
line 2.  ['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] is better written in dot notation.
line 3   Missing semicolon.
line 4   Missing semicolon.
```

I understand why Google decided to leave out the semicolons, they're both on statements that are the last in their block and it saves 2 bytes. But could anybody explain why they decided to write this:

```
i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r
```

Instead of this:

```
i.GoogleAnalyticsObject=r
```

Where the latter is actually 3 bytes shorter and according to "[JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)" should also be slightly faster.

Comment: They could also save a bunch of bytes if they renamed it (and all references) to `i.GAO`

Comment: True, but in default setup that means you would make a global (window scoped) variable called "GAO" which has a much higher risk of conflicting with others than "GoogleAnalyticsObject".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible they use the string notation over the dot notation, because a string will not be altered during minification.

Answer (score 0):

Without having one of their actual engineers show up and answer, we are left to guess. This is my best guess:

The performance differences between dot and bracket notation are negligible (http://jsperf.com/dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation/2), so I doubt that even factored into the decision. IMO the most likely reasons for this is the change are:

- A coding style preference with their engineering team
- Perhaps i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] can take more forms then just 'GoogleAnalyticsObject', possibly with special characters, hashes, etc. that would not work with the dot notation

I think the latter is the most likely as it is one of the main reasons to use brackets over dot, however that is just my opinion.

Comment: Not sure if this is a factor, but putting it as a string will also ensure it does not get renamed when minifying.

Comment: great point, I was thinking it could've been a compiler issue as well but decided to remove that from the list

Comment: @xbonez that actually makes a lot of sense! I've done this myself a few times but forgot to think about it in this case. Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it?